# Regex to match this: "Late Fee 81245 on 11/29/2014"?

Tags: regex

The Late Fee number is any integer and the Date will always be in that format.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
late fee \d+ on \d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}
```

I always try mine out on http://regexper.com/

Comment: This is perfect, thanks for the bonus website.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pick up the month, day, and year separately:

```
"^Late Fee (\d+) on (\d\d)/(\d\d)/(\d\d)$"
```

If you just want to pick up the date as a unit:

```
"^Late Fee (\d+) on (\d\d/\d\d/\d\d)$"
```

Comment: Small correction, need to grab 4 digits for the year not 2.

Comment: Also the month and day could be improved by allowing 1 or 2 digits, it is unclear from the OP if single digit months/days would always be represented with 2 digits.

Answer (score 1):

```
Late Fee \d+ on (0?[1-9]|1[0-2])/(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])/(19|20)\d\d
```

Answer (score 1):

If the month and day could be 1 or 2 digits try this:

```
Late Fee \d+ on \d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}
```